# Removing Flag Bits stored in an Array

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I currently have the transmitter array that stores 01111110 0110111 01111110 
I want the receiver array to store 0110111. I want to eliminate all the 01111110 bits.

But I am receiving 0110111 01111110. Why is it that my code is only removing the first 01111110 bits in the transmitter array?

My attempted code is as below:

```
#define nosbits 23
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h> 

int main()
{

   unsigned transmitter[nosbits] = { 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0 };
   unsigned receiver[nosbits];
   int count = 0;
   int outputreceivercount = 0;
   bool flag = false;

   for (int i = 0; i < nosbits; i++)
   {

       if (transmitter[i] == 1)
       {
          count++;
       }
       else
       {
          count = 0;
       }

       receiver[outputreceivercount++] = transmitter[i];

       //After 5 consecutive 1s, if the next two bits are '10', then the flag is detected. 
       if ((transmitter[i + 1] == 1) && (transmitter[i + 2] == 0) && count == 5)
       {
           if (!(flag))
           {
              flag = true;
              i = i + 2;
              outputreceivercount = 0;
              count = 0;
           }  
        }
   }


   printf("Bitstream before removing flag bits:\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < nosbits; i++)
   {
      printf("%d", transmitter[i]);
   }
   printf("\n\n");


   printf("Bitstream after removing flag bits:\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < outputreceivercount; i++)
   {
      printf("%d", receiver[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");

   system("pause");
   return 0; 

}
```

Comment: What does *remove all the bits of a flag* mean?

Comment: @Pablo sorry for not being clear, I meant removing 01111110 as those are the bits of a Flag.

Comment: It's still not clear to me though. What do you mean by *removing*? Left shit, right shift, setting them to 0? And *removing* them from where?

Comment: @Pablo I want to remove all the bits 01111110 from the transmitter array as can be seen from my code. If you can observe there are two 'flags' in the beginning there is 01111110 and in the last 8 bits there are 01111110. But my program only removed the first 8 bits that is the 01111110 in the beginning of the transmitter array.

Comment: I see your code, but I don't get your intentions, because I don't understand what you mean by *remove*. Technically speaking, you can set a bit either to 0 or to 1, you cannot "remove" bits, that's why I'm asking what you mean by *remove*.

Comment: The question is not very clear, but the answer probably is: use a state machine.

Comment: @pablo  I tried to make the question easier to understand. Sorry I am not clear I am trying my best here.

Comment: @wildplasser I tried to make the question easier to understand. Sorry I am not clear I am trying my best here

Comment: Next question: what should happen if there is an extra bit, (for instance: a '0' at the beginning) aka "framing error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) if you need to detect flags in multiple of 8bit, you had better to use characters, so when you detect the byte 0x7e, then eliminate it.  This is applicable when you are using the flat character in asynchronous lines, that transmit only 8bit bytes.  (Your sample data has only seven bits of data between flags, so I'll assume this is not the case.)

2) if you need to detect the flag on a per bit basis, then you face the HDLC framing problem, that has two parts:  a) the flag is detected when you detect 6 joint `1` bits, and b) transmitter inserts a `0` bits if more than 5 `1` bits are in sequence (to ensure transparency).  For this second part you need also to delete the 6th `0` bit after a sequence of 5 `1` bits also.  I don't know if you want this, but your *flag* seems extremely similar to an HDLC flag to assume you are not actually studying this protocol.

This problem can be faced with a finite automaton.  The NFA equivalent, to detect this is:

```
 0,1 
,--. 
|  / 
| /  
|v  1       1       1       1       1      0 
(0)--->(1P)--->(2P)--->(3P)--->(4P)--->(5)--->(6D)
 |                                      |      _
 .                                      .     / \ 1
  \                                      \ 1  | V
   \0                                     `-->(7B)
    \
     \   1      1       1       1       1       0      
     (8)--->(9)--->(10)--->(11)--->(12)--->(13)--->(14F)
```

Where

- `([1-4]P)` Accepting state, print the number of `1` chars shown in the state number, (e.g. for state `(3P)` print `111`.)
- `(6D)` Accepting state, print `11111`.
- `(7B)` Accepting state. BREAK condition detected.
- `(14F)` Accepting state. Flag detected.
- All others are not accepting states.  The automaton has to continue 
  matching states until no more accepting states can be reached, to output
  the string of the last accepting state visited as output (e.g. if the last accepting state was 6D, then it has to output '11111'.  In case the last state visited includes several accepting states, the priority order is:

  ```
  14F, 7B, 6D, 4P, 3P, 2P, 1P
  ```

This NFA recognises 8 kinds of strings (I'll express them as regexps),  namely: `0`, `01111110`, `1`, `11`, `111`, `1111`, `111110`, and `11111111*`. If a flag is accepted, you have to check also if the number of bits is a multiple of 8, as you can have arbitrary bit sequences with this protocol.  Probably you don't, as the sample data you posted includes only seven bits.  It could be represented by the following `lex(1)` pattern:

```
%%
0         ECHO; 
01111110  putchar('F');
1111111*  putchar('B');
1         |
11        |
111       |
1111      ECHO;
111110    fputs("11111", stdout);
.         ;
%%
```

## NOTE

Below is a complete DFA that converts the input bits into the following
alphabet (for your problem, it only needs to substitute the `"F"` and `"B"` strings with empty ones `""`):

```
/*
 * DFA to implement.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define F(x) __FILE__":%d:%s: " x, __LINE__, __func__
#ifndef DEBUG
#define DEBUG 0
#endif

#if DEBUG
#define D(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define D(...)
#endif

#define E(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)

char *names[] = {
        "START"    , "ST0"      , "ST_1"     , "ST01"     ,
        "ST_11"    , "ST011"    , "ST_111"   , "ST0111"   ,
        "ST_1111"  , "ST01111"  , "ST_11111" , "ST011111" ,
        "ST1111111", "ST"       , "ST0111111", "ST1"      ,
        "ST11"     , "ST111"    , "ST1111"   , "ST11111"  ,
};
static enum st {
        START    , ST0      , ST_1     , ST01     , ST_11    ,
        ST011    , ST_111   , ST0111   , ST_1111  , ST01111  ,
        ST_11111 , ST011111 , ST1111111, ST       , ST0111111,
        ST1      , ST11     , ST111    , ST1111   , ST11111  ,
} state = START;

char flag[] = "F";
char brk[] = "B";


struct tab_entry {
    enum st t_next;
    char *t_insert;
} tab[][2] = {
        /* INPUT                                          */
        /* STATE            0/OUTPUT   | 1/OUTPUT         */
        /* ========================+================      */
        /* START     */     ST0, 0,         ST_1,      0,       
        /* ST0       */     ST0, "0",       ST01,      0,     
        /* ST_1      */     ST0, 0,         ST_11,     0,     
        /* ST01      */     ST0, "01",      ST011,     0,    
        /* ST_11     */     ST0, 0,         ST_111,    0,    
        /* ST011     */     ST0, "011",     ST0111,    0,   
        /* ST_111    */     ST0, 0,         ST_1111,   0,    
        /* ST0111    */     ST0, "0111",    ST01111,   0,
        /* ST_1111   */     ST0, 0,         ST_11111,  0,
        /* ST01111   */     ST0, "01111",   ST011111,  0,
        /* ST_11111  */     ST0, 0,         ST1111111, 0, /* break */
        /* ST011111  */     ST, "011111",   ST0111111, 0,
        /* ST1111111 */     ST0, brk,       ST1111111, 0,
        /* ST        */     ST0, 0,         ST1,       0,
        /* ST0111111 */     ST , flag,      ST1111111, 0, /* break */
        /* ST1       */     ST0, "1",       ST11,      0,
        /* ST11      */     ST0, "11",      ST111,     0,
        /* ST111     */     ST0, "111",     ST1111,    0,
        /* ST1111    */     ST0, "1111",    ST11111,   0,
        /* ST11111   */     ST,  "11111",   ST1111111, 0, /* break */
};

void hdlc_rst()
{
    state = START;
}

char *hdlc_dec(char *out, int outsz, char *in)
{
    char *res = out;
    int c;

    while ((c = *in++) != 0) {
        switch(c) {
        case '0': case '1':;
            struct tab_entry *entry = &tab[state][c - '0'];
            if (state != START) fputs("", stderr);
            D(F("State: %s(%d), Input: '%c'\n"),
                    names[state], state, c);
            if (entry->t_insert) {
                int n = snprintf(out, outsz,
                        "%s", entry->t_insert);
                D(F("Append \"%s\"\n"), entry->t_insert);
                out += n;
                outsz -= n;
            }
            D(F("State %s(%d) -> %s(%d)\n"),
                    names[state], state,
                    names[entry->t_next], entry->t_next);
            state = entry->t_next;
            break;
        default:
            E(F("Invalid character '%c' in input string\n"), c);
            break;
        } /* switch */
    } /* while */
    char *p = tab[state][0].t_insert;
    snprintf(out, outsz, "%s", p ? p : "");
    return res;
} /* hdlc_dec */

char *hdlc_enc(char *out, int outsz, char *in)
{
    char *res = out;
    char c;
    int n_ones = 0;

    while ((c = *in++) != 0) {
        int n = 0;
        switch(c) {
        case 'F': case 'f':
            n = snprintf(out, outsz, "01111110");
            n_ones = 0;
            break;
        case 'B': case 'b':
            n = snprintf(out, outsz, "1111111");
            n_ones = 0;
            break;
        case '0':
            n = snprintf(out, outsz, "0");
            n_ones = 0;
            break;
        case '1':
            n = snprintf(out, outsz, "1");
            n_ones++;
            if (n_ones == 5) {
                n += snprintf(out+1, outsz-1, "0");
                n_ones = 0;
            }
            break;
        default:
            D(F("Invalid character '%c' in input string\n"), c);
            break;
        } /* switch */
        outsz -= n;
        out += n;
    } /* while */
    return res;
} /* hdlc_enc */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    static char linea[10240], out[10240];
    char *(*hdlc)(char *out, int outsz, char *in) = hdlc_dec;

    if (strcmp(argv[0], "hdlc_dec") == 0)
        hdlc = hdlc_dec;
    else if (strcmp(argv[0], "hdlc_enc") == 0)
        hdlc = hdlc_enc;

    while(fgets(linea, sizeof linea, stdin)) {
        int l = strlen(linea);
        if (linea[l-1] == '\n') linea[--l] = '\0';
        hdlc(out, sizeof out, linea);
        D(F("%s ==> %s\n"), linea, out);
        printf("%s\n", out);
    } /* while */

} /* main */
```

To compile, use the following command:

```
cc -o hdlc_enc hdlc.c
ln hdlc_enc hdlc_dec
```

or, if you want debug traces of how the automaton works, use

```
cc -o hdlc_enc -DDEBUG=1 hdlc.c
ln hdlc_enc hdlc_dec
```

and you'll have both commands `hdlc_enc` to encode standard input, and `hdlc_dec` to decode it.  To encode, use `F` for flag, `B` for BREAK, `0` and `1` (no restrictions) It will make `0` insertions at the proper places.  To decode, just feed a sequence of bits, and it will transform flags into `F`, BREAKs into `B` and eliminate spureous `0`s inserted by encoder. (after five `1` bits a `0` is inserted, to ensure transparency)

I have compiled the automaton by hand, so probably it's not optimum in the number of states, but 18 states is not too much.

The states names stand for the prefix `ST` followed by what has been read too far and not yet output because we cannot decide if it is a flag, break or a simple data bit sequence.  States anchored to the stream beginning are prefixed by `ST_`.

## NOTE 2

A DFA that, in addition recognises only multiple of 8 bit patterns between flags is far out of the scope of this answer.  You can count the bits between flags and see if they are multiple of eight bits on flag recognition, as the DFA should have N1xN2 states (around 80 states) and this makes it no worth to implement.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing reply. I had already solved the problem by simply storing the destuffed databits after detecting a flag. And yes you were right as the implementation I am doing is identical to the HDLC. Despite already solving the problem before you answered yours is definitely the best answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need the "flag" variable to detect the flag.
Replace the following code and see if it helps.

```
//After 5 consecutive 1s, if the next two bits are '10', then the flag is detected. 
   if ((transmitter[i + 1] == 1) && (transmitter[i + 2] == 0) && count == 5)
   {                        
        i = i + 2;      
        outputreceivercount -= (count+1);
        count = 0;      
    }
```

This can be optimized more if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, you check the state of `flag` before you perform what looks to be your "remove" section - you require `flag` to be false before you "remove" the bits. The first time such a flag is detected you set `flag` to true. It then stays true for all subsequent loops, so your "remove" section can never execute again.

In more general terms, I'm somewhat confused by your "remove" section - every time a "flag" is detected, you start overwriting `receiver` from the 0th element? What happens in a string such as "0111111001101110111111010101010" - what would you expect your output to be?

Comment: My transmitter array has:  01111110  0110111  01111110. I want to receive:  0110111. But the way I programmed it I received  0110111 01111110.

Comment: Yes, and I've just explained (one of) the reasons why! But, what happens if your transmitter has, for example, 01111110 011011 01111110 101010 - what would you want to receive?

Comment: With this transmitter = 0111111001101110111111010101010 I expect the receiver to be =   011011110101010. I want to store all of the bits apart from 01111110

Comment: In which case, your code as written would not do that, even if it detected every instance of your "flag". Every time you detect a "flag", you reset `outputrecievercount` to 0 - this has the effect of, combined with the line
    `receiver[outputreceivercount++] = transmitter[i];`
beginning to overwrite your `receiver` array starting with the bits after the "flag". In my example, you would end up receiving 101010.

Comment: how do you handle this sequence? `011111101111111101111110` ???
how do you handle this one? `0111111011111011101111110` ??? how do you handle `011111101011111100000000` ???

Comment: @ACascarino, in HDLC the pattern you post in your answer should be `F0110111F1010101`  with waiting for the last `0` to decide if it is the beginning of a new flag.  (flags are marked with `F` in the output string)